# Windows 7 Profile Default Image Files Location

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I'm looking for the location to the images that are used next user's accounts when a user logs into a windows 7 system. Can someone point me in the right direction.

The following is a screenshot of the pictures I'm referring to:
[image]

Need the location so that I can add/edit/remove images via a program (E.g. Different icons for different employee types.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but the location appears to be `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Default Pictures`.

Comment: Need the location so I can add/remove/edit via programming :)

Answer (score 3):

I only have access to Windows XP here, but looking in the source code of `picturespage.js` inside `nusrmgr.cpl` (the users Control Panel applet), it loads the pictures using this code:

```
EnumPics(top.window.GetShell().NameSpace(35).Self.Path + "\\Microsoft\\User Account Pictures\\Default Pictures");
```

[Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 35 (0x23) is apparently `ssfCOMMONAPPDATA`.

The 'Common App Data' path is [generally] `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\` on XP, and `C:\ProgramData\` on Vista and above. That path can retrieved through the Windows API by calling [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it here:

**All - Default Pictures**

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Default Pictures
```

**Standard - Administrator**

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\user.bmp
```

**Guest**

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\guest.bmp
```